# How to override default display values for a select field for foreign keys in the Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm creating models, where each model should be related with a user, like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

But then in the Django Admin, for an `Item`, it shows a `select` field with all the users listed by their usernames. In addition to their usernames, I also need to display each user's `first_name` and `last_name`.

How can all three fields be displayed together within that select list in the Django Admin interface?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create custom `Form` for this and set form attribute in your `ModelAdmin`.

In that `Form` you will need to override form field type of `user` field on model to custom `ModelChoiceField`.

`ModelChoiceField` has a method called `label_from_instance`, you need to override that to get full name.

### Example code

```
######################################
## models.py ##
######################################

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

######################################
## forms.py ##
######################################

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import Item


class CustomUserChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return obj.get_full_name()


class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = CustomUserChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Item

######################################
## admin.py ##
######################################

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Item
from .forms import ItemForm


class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ItemForm


admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

### Source Code Reference

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.5/django/forms/models.py#L948

### Related Questions

1. [Django admin - change ForeignKey display text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836740/django-admin-change-foreignkey-display-text)
2. [Django forms: how to dynamically create ModelChoiceField labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958792/django-forms-how-to-dynamically-create-modelchoicefield-labels)
3. [Change Django ModelChoiceField to show users' full names rather
   than usernames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167824/change-django-modelchoicefield-to-show-users-full-names-rather-than-usernames)
4. [Django show get_full_name() instead or username in model form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966483/django-show-get-full-name-instead-or-username-in-model-form)
5. [django: customizing display of ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695754/django-customizing-display-of-modelmultiplechoicefield)
6. [django how to display users full name in FilteredSelectMultiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510849/django-how-to-display-users-full-name-in-filteredselectmultiple)
7. [Django ModelChoiceField drop down box custom population](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657344/django-modelchoicefield-drop-down-box-custom-population)
8. [customize select in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414853/customize-select-in-django-admin)
9. [Use method other than **unicode** in ModelChoiceField Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437060/use-method-other-than-unicode-in-modelchoicefield-django)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The last line has a typo I think. It should be "admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)".

Answer (score 2):

Django uses unicode(obj) (or the related function, str(obj)) in a number of places. Most notably, to display an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object.

Please see `__unicode__` from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/

You can change `__unicode__` method of User class. See below example codes.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def myunicode(self):
    return self.get_full_name()

# Create your models here.
class Item(models.Model):
    User.__unicode__ = myunicode
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: True, but in the case of a selection list generated for a `models.ForeignKey(User)`, the `unicode` function being called is the one for the `User`, so you still get a list of usernames.

Comment: Yes. but, how about change User class's `__unicode__` method to my own at runtime? Please see my updated answer with example.

Comment: It's risky. Since that's part of Django itself, and other apps can use it, you might get unexpected behavior from the other apps which expect  `unicode` to return the username. The custom form keeps the change confined to just the part that needs it. BTW, you could also do `User.__unicode__ = lambda s: s.get_full_name()`.